# to_datetime vs to_pydatetime trying to convert str to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with one columns that is a date and a time and is a string.
The format of the date and time is like this: `4/27/2021 12:39`
This is what I have so far to try and convert the string into a datetime:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(open_times)):
    date = df.iloc[i]['Open Datetime']
    good_date = date.to_datetime()
    # good_date = date.topydatetime()
    new_list.append(good_date)
```

I have used `to_pydatetime()` in the past however the string was in a different format.
When I run the code from above I get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'` and I get the same error when I run the commented out line except with `to_pydatetime`.
Any thoughts on how to resolve this error? I think that this is happening because the format of the string is different than it typically is.

Comment: `to_datetime` and `to_pydatetime` expect to work with pandas' datetime type, which is a 64-bit integer.  They don't work with strings at all.  In your past efforts, pandas must have recognized the string format and imported them as datetime64 types.  You will have to use something like `datetime.datetime.strptime` to translate these strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` to convert a string to datetime type

```py
from datetime import datetime

for i in range(len(open_times)):
    date = df.iloc[i]['Open Datetime']
    good_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

But you could use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) directly

```
df['Open Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Datetime'])

# Convert a column to list
new_list = df['Open Datetime'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: "You *should* use pd.to_datetime directly." :) It's much more efficient than a for loop

Comment: Oh, I really like both ways! I didn't know that you could just directly convert the data frame. The only reason I like the first one over the second is that the second one is in a weird format. It gives integers. For example, it gives  1619527140000000000 as the value of one DateTime and I tried converting it with datetime.fromtimestamp(1619527140000000000  / 1e3) but failed

Comment: @svlad It shouldn't give you integers. How about `df['Open Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`?